# how to exclude single quotes from the reg expression /\W+/ in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a paragraph of text using regex, but `/\W+/` splits `can't` into `can` and `t`.
Is there any way to define a regular expression that splits whenever a character other than a-z,A-Z,0-9 and '(single quotes) is encountered?

```
 text=text.split(/\W+/);
```

Comment: Yes, split on `[^\w']`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen u mean  text=text.split(/^\w'/)?

Comment: No, that's not what I wrote.  You can split on a negative character class which excludes word characters plus single quote.  If you add some sample data to your question, maybe more can be said.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen text is a string which contain some sentences,i am making a word counting application,and the current regexp splits something like can't into 'can' and 't' and i want to consider can't as a single word

Comment: Can your text also contain words which are escaped in single quotes?  In other words, is single quote always an apostrophe, or could it be used in a different way?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is always an apostrophe,Thanks

Comment: What version of JavaScript are you using?  Is it a recent version of Node, or some browser version?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i am running this on browser,the text comes from a textarea element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex splits on everything you asked for , that is a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and ' :

```
text=text.split(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\']/);
```